# Inserting multiple rows from php foreach

Tags: php, mysql

I have an html form with dynamic (user-determined) number of rows, each with several inputs; I'm trying to achieve a MySQL query which will insert rows
into the db table, more or less row-for-row (although there is a value $_POSTing from outside this table which I will also add to the INSERT).

I'm retrieving these values like this:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $lineItems = array();
        foreach ($_POST['date'] as $i => $value) {
            $customer = $_POST['customer'][$i]; // this value is from *outside* the line items table
            $date = $_POST['date'][$i];
            $time = $_POST['time'][$i];
            $fee = $_POST['fee'][$i];

            $lineItems[] = "('$customer', '$date', '$time', '$fee')";

        // I realize the query should be outside the loop, but what I'm trying to do is something like this (pseudo-code):
            $query = "INSERT INTO Line_Items (CUSTOMER, DATE, TIME, FEE) VALUES ". implode(", ", $lineItems)
            . "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            CUSTOMER    = VALUES(CUSTOMER),
            DATE        = VALUES(DATE),
            TIME        = VALUES(TIME),
            FEE     = VALUES(FEE)
            ";

        }
    }
?>
```

With this query - inside or outside the loop - I'm only inserting values from the last row of inputs; can someone please explain with an example how
to construct a query to insert multiple line items and the appropriate query? Thank you so much.

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) like the ones you have here. **Never** put `$_POST` data directly in a query.

Comment: It seems to work fine if you put the insert statement outside the loop...

Comment: Thanks @tadman. I'm just trying to get this thing wired up, I assure you I will be revisiting injection prevention.

Comment: You should fix this now before you forget, because when you forget [terrible things can happen](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/security/bitcoin-market-flash-crash-and-database-leak-from-mt-gox/8811). If you're using a database layer like PDO, use **placeholder values**. String interpolation is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop you will get a row for each line in the post - outside the loop you will only insert the last row.

If you just need the last row - then there is no need to loop over the entire set to get to it.

You could count the rows - and then target the last row directly - see php

```
count()
```

Comment: Thank you. I certainly want all the rows, never just the last one.

Comment: Thank you. I certainly want all the rows, never just the last one. With the revised query still inside the loop, I'm getting a mysql error, prob related to the ON DUPLICATE KEY part. Tearing my hair out

Answer (score 0):

Change line 
`$lineItems[] = "('$customer', '$date', '$time', '$fee')";`
 to 
`$lineItems[] = "(".$customer.",".$date.",".$time.",".$fee.")";`

Comment: Thanks @user2340218. Now, using this:

$lineItems[] = "(".$customer.",".$date.",".$time.",".$fee.")";

$queryx = "INSERT INTO Invoice_Hours (CUSTOMER, DATE, TIME, FEE) VALUES ". implode(", ", $lineItems) . "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
CUSTOMER = VALUES(CUSTOMER),
DATE = VALUES(DATE),
TIME = VALUES(TIME),
FEE = VALUES(FEE)
";
I'm getting a mysql error, re: the ON DUPLICATE. Any suggestion?

Comment: What are the unique keys in your "Line_items" table? If "customer" is a unique key or primary key use the following: "INSERT INTO Line_Items (CUSTOMER, DATE, TIME, FEE) VALUES ". implode(", ", $lineItems). "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE           
            DATE        = VALUES(DATE),
            TIME        = VALUES(TIME),
            FEE     = VALUES(FEE);"