# Insert array where checkboxes are checked

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox

Being new to PHP and MySQL, I've picked up quite a few things reading here. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103010/inserting-multiple-rows-from-php-foreach) is about the closest question I can find relative to my issue. I borrowed some from the solution but it's only gotten me so far.

I populate a form with table data from a `SELECT` statement, currently 15 rows. Each row from the result has a checkbox and corresponding data. There's also a textarea in the form.

I need to insert the text input from the textarea along with the `Case_No` and `Client_No` associated with the checkbox, into a different table...only where the checkbox is checked. Only the text will be same for each row. None of the unchecked checkboxes should be included in the `INSERT`.

I realize the answer is probably some sort of loop, but I don't have much experience with inserting from loops, only displaying data from loops.

Here is my form:

```
<form method="post" name="group_note" action="group_test.php?Counselor=<?php echo $_GET['Counselor'];?>"/>
<table border="1" width="650" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#999999">
<tr><th>Group Note</th></tr>
<tr><td><textarea name="Note" rows="10" cols="115"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><th align="left">Select clients below to receive this group note &nbsp; <input type="submit" value="Add Group Note"></th></tr>
</table>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#999999">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th bgcolor="#009999">Select</th>
    <th bgcolor="#009999">Name</th>
    <th bgcolor="#009999">Case No.</th>
    <th bgcolor="#009999">Client No.</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php foreach ($dbh -> query($sql) as $row) { ?>        
<tr> 
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="groupselect[]" value="<?php echo $row['Case_No'];?>" /></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['FirstName']. " " . $row['LastName']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Case_No']; ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $row['Client_No']; ?><input type="hidden" name="Client_No" value="<?php echo $row['Client_No']; ?>"/></td>

<?php  }  ?>
</tbody>
</table>
    <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="group_note">
</form>
```

And the Insert statement:

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "group_note")) {
try
    {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_database; charset=utf8", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $insertGroup = array();
        foreach ($_POST['groupselect'] as $i => $value) {
        $GroupNote_CaseNo=$_POST['groupselect'][$i];
        $GroupNote_ClientID=$_POST['Client_No'][$i];
        $GroupNote=$_POST['Note'];
        $insertGroup[]="(".$GroupNote_CaseNo.", ".$GroupNote_ClientID.", ".$GroupNote.")";
        $Note = "INSERT INTO group_note GroupNote_CaseNo, GroupNote_ClientID, GroupNote VALUES ". implode(", ", $insertGroup). "GroupNote_CaseNo=VALUES(GroupNote_CaseNo), GroupNote_ClientID= VALUES(GroupNote_ClientID), GroupNote=VALUES(GroupNote)";
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->closeCursor();       
    }
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
    $message = 'Something not working right!!';
    }
}
```

When I select two or three checkboxes and insert some text, on submit I get this result from `var_dump($_POST['groupselect'])`

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(22) "(1518-R, 4, This note)" [1]=> string(22)
"(1534-R, 3, This note)" [2]=> string(22) "(4062-R, 3, This note)" }
```

The `ClientNo` is only showing one digit, and they are three digits long. If I remove the [$i] following `$GroupNote_ClientID=$_POST['Client_No']`, I'll get all three digits, but only from the first checkbox row selected:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(22) "(1518-R, 4, This note)" [1]=> string(22) 
"(1534-R, 3, This note)" [2]=> string(22) "(4062-R, 3, This note)" }
```

In any case, nothing is getting inserted into the table. Depending on the variable syntax, the PHP error log shows "Undefined variable: insertGroup" and/or "Undefined variable: insertGroup".

Also, I'm aware of the dangers of `$_POST` variables. My database is an internal-use only, on our intranet. No outside access.

Comment: If you'd bothered reading up on MySQL's [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) syntax, and actually bothering check if your query calls actually succeeded, you'd have been TOLD about your sql syntax errors. But instead you chose to go with the "nothing could ever go wrong" programming school, and now you're suffering for it. Never **EVER** assume success when dealing with external resources. Always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally got it working. First, the recommendation from @CBroe about adding `[]` to `ClientNo` in the form picked up the 2nd variable I needed. The other part involved making changes to the `INSERT` statement using placeholders for a `PREPARE` statement. Can I credit @Marc B for that?

I also bound the values, though I do think accepting the `$_POST` input is unsafe. My only defense is this is not a public-facing database.

Here is the result (*the form didn't change, it's still in the original question*), compare to the original:

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "group_note")) {
try
{
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_database; charset=utf8", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$insertGroup = array();
foreach ($_POST['groupselect'] as $i => $value) {
$GroupNote_CaseNo=isset($_POST['groupselect']) ? ($_POST['groupselect'][$i]) : null;
$GroupNote_ClientID=isset($_POST['ClientNo']) ? ($_POST['ClientNo'][$i]) : null;
$GroupNote=$_POST['Note'];
$insertGroup[]="(".$GroupNote_CaseNo.",".$GroupNote_ClientID.",".$GroupNote.")";
$Note = 'INSERT INTO group_note (GroupNote_CaseNo,GroupNote_ClientID,GroupNote) VALUES (:GroupNote_CaseNo, :GroupNote_ClientID, :GroupNote)';
$stmt=$dbh->prepare($Note);
$stmt->bindValue(':GroupNote_CaseNo', ($_POST['groupselect'][$i]));
$stmt->bindValue(':GroupNote_ClientID', ($_POST['ClientNo'][$i]));
$stmt->bindValue(':GroupNote', $_POST['Note']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->closeCursor(); 
}
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
$message = $e;
}
}
```

Some of the parentheses in the bindings may be unnecessary, but I'm not a developer. It worked for me, hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

> The ClientNo is only showing one digit, and they are three digits long. If I remove the [$i] following $GroupNote_ClientID=$_POST['Client_No'], I'll get all three digits, but only from the first checkbox row selected

You used `name="Client_No"` on the hidden input fields that hold the values – you missed the `[]` that you used for the checkboxes, and therefor you only get the last value, not as an array, but a mere string. And accessing a string via a numeric index returns its single characters.

Now with adding the `[]` to the name of the hidden input field, you won’t be done here. For `type=checkbox`, there is only a value send when the input is checked; but *all* of the hidden fields will be send. And since the index of the resulting array is automatically generated, you will get a disparity between checkbox values and hidden input values. To avoid that, you can specify the index upfront, by naming the input fields like this, `name="foo[0]"`, `name="foo[1]"`, etc. If you do that for both fields, you will get the values matched up correctly in your array.

But then you will still have to take into account that indexes in the checkbox array might be “missing”, not set. So you should loop over the hidden input value array instead – that will have all indexes set, no gaps. And then you use the current index to check whether the checkbox array has a corresponding element with the given key (`isset`).

Instead of a numeric array index, you could also use your client number to begin with.

If you name the checkboxes like so, `name="foo[igf]`", `name="foo[dkh]`", etc., then you won’t need the hidden input fields any more – every checked checkbox will automatically be associated with its client number.

Comment: Adding the [] to the ClientName input certainly worked! I feel pretty befuddled by the rest of your answer. Because the checkboxes are dynamically generated, I don't know how I'd be able _to specify the index upfront by renaming the input fields_.  The number of rows generated might be 15 in one situation, 8 in another, and 2 in another. Though I've tested by checking _some_ boxes and skipping others, the resulting array seems to keep up with the correct values.

I understand your intent as far as the numeric array, there is an auto-incremented index in the table, if that would work.

Comment: Perhaps I should have qualified "...input certainly worked". The rows still don't get inserted into the table, though the output of `var_dump $insertGroup` shows all of the necessary data to be inserted (CaseNo, ClientNo, GroupNote...[0]=> string(24) "(1518-R, 336, This note)". Something fails at a point that I can't discern. Nothing shows up in the php_errors log.

Comment: Maybe you should check what possible exceptions actually have to say, instead of just replacing them with a generic error message of your own.

Comment: Of course your are right, I didn't take a minute to realize that. The output of PDO Exception $e is "We are unable to process your request. Please try again later". Very cryptic and not too helpful. I enabled MySQL logging and can only tell that

Comment: (cont.) I enabled MySQL logging and can only tell that the INSERT is not reaching the server. Only the SELECT shows up in the log. INSERT on other forms are working and show up in the log. Searching now for some hints to the error message.